# OpenAI Gym environment cannot be loaded in Google Colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I'm trying to train a DQN in google colab so that I can test the performance of the TPU. Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')

AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'LunarLander'
```

I know this is a common error, and I had this before on my local machine. I was able to fix it with commands like:

```
!pip install box2d box2d-kengz
!pip install Box2D
!pip install -e '.[box2d]'
```

While this worked on my local machine, on google colab is it not. I can't get rid of the error. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

On a fresh colab, I simply installed box2d-py via

```
!pip3 install box2d-py
```

and it worked.

Try it on a new colab it should work.

Comment: Restart the notebook and then install by `!pip install box2d-py`

Comment: I tried this, but didn't work, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute at the beginning a cell with the code:

```
!sudo apt-get install swig build-essential python-dev python3-dev
```

This should solve your problem and you will be able to install this library in google colab